# Using array merge when array doesn't have value

Tags: php, arrays

I am wondering is it possible to merge 2 arrays that look this:

```
$array1 = array("a","b","c");
$array2 = array('c'=>array("blah"=>"5", "moreblah"=>"5"));
$merge = array_merge($array1,$array2);
print_r($merge);
```

Running this will give me this output:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [c] => Array ( [blah] => 5 [moreblah] => 5 ) )
```

But the output I want is something similar to this:

```
Array( [a]=>Array([blah]=>0, [moreblah]=>0), [b]=>Array([blah]=>0, [moreblah]=>0), [c]=>Array([blah]=>5, [moreblah]=>5))
```

So for the first array I want the values to become the keys and then `blah` and `moreblah` to be added and set as 0 if they are not present in array 2. Also for array 2 if there is a repeat such as `c` in the example array 2 would just overwrite the `c` index and create the output I wrote above.

Is this possible? If so can I do it with a built in method or would I have to use a for loop to try get it working?

Edit:As has been pointed out to be it is not possible. Can someone explain what type of function I would need to make to be able to get the output I would want?

Comment: That's not a merge. You're trying to impose the structure of one array onto another using the other's values to put into the "template". That's something you should do with a loop. PHP has a decent selection of array functions, but expecting php to have a dedicated function for EVERY possible array operation, let along every possible array structure is just expecting too much.

Comment: Just write your own function to recreate an array that looks like the one you want..?

Comment: @Dieter I am not sure how? Can you give me an idea of how please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

EDIT: This only works when you know the keys in the second array, is this known or not? Else i change the code..

```
$array1 = array("a", "b", "c");
$array2 = array('c' => array("blah" => "5", "moreblah" => "5"));

$newArray = "";

foreach ($array1 as $a1) {
    if (key_exists($a1, $array2)) {
        //check if blah and / or moreblah is set else set the value to 0 or something else
        if (key_exists("blah", $array2[$a1])) {
            $blah = $array2[$a1]["blah"];
        } else {
            $blah = 0;
        }

        if (key_exists("moreblah", $array2[$a1])) {
            $moreblah = $array2[$a1]["moreblah"];
        } else {
            $moreblah = 0;
        }


        $newArray[$a1] = array("blah" => $blah, "moreblah" => $moreblah);
    } else {
        $newArray[$a1] = array("blah" => 0, "moreblah" => 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try add this to my application it doesn't see to work for some reason. The blah values are always 0 even when they are present in the second array, but I will mark it as answer because I think it is an issue with the rest of my code because I have tried it on [writecodeonline](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: I tested this myself, so it should work fine, but as I edited, this code is only good if u know the keys in the second array..

Comment: I do know the `blah` and `moreblah` keys but when I print out the `$newarray` and `$array2` heres what I get: `Array([a]=>Array([blah]=>0, [moreblah]=>0), [b]=>Array([blah]=>0, [moreblah]=>0), [c]=>Array([blah]=>0, [moreblah]=>0))` and for `$array2` I get `Array([c]=>Array([blah]=>10, [moreblah]=>12))` Any reason for this?

Comment: I have no idea, when I test the code i pasted here, I get the exact same thing you just pasted, so I guess your $array2 is different :P

Comment: Ok I think I have worked it out. For simplicity and to make the question more generalised I have used values like `a` and `b` but instead of that I am using a `date` which uses strtotime and I think that is the issue so now I am trying to store the array as a string and then hopefully it will work. Your function however works excellently. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array("a", "b", "c");
$structured = array_fill_keys($array1, array('blah' => 0, 'moreblah' => 0));
```

Should give you the array you want as a base. Then it's a matter of looping over your data and adding them where needed.